# Is MySQL 5.5 worth it?

Tags: dovecot, mysql5.1, mysql5.5

I am about to setup a couple of LAMP servers using Ubuntu 10.04. The problem is that I have noticed that Dovecot needs the MySQL-common package to work. I don't want to install that package since I am going to use the MySQL 5.5 binaries...so I don't know if I should install all the packages of MySQL 5.1 using apt-get or just leave MySQL-common 5.1 and use the 5.5 version for the applications.

What would you do?. To use MySQL 5.1? or MySQL 5.5 and the 5.1 MySQL common?.

Comment: do you have specific reasons for wanting to go to 5.5?

Comment: well, I read that the performance is better, specially with innodb tables :)

Comment: If you're looking for pure throughput, it has been said that 5.1 is a bit quicker http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=483402225932

Answer (score 3):

Use whichever version is latest on your distribution of choice.  I'd suggest you use Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, and the current version of that is.. MySQL 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.7

That means that you'll get easy to install binaries `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` , and support for them from the ubuntu community, because things will happen as expected.

Mixing and matching mysql-server and mysql-client versions is likely to fail in surprising and unexpected ways.  Especially at 5pm on a Friday. 
Don't Do It.

If dovecot requires MySQL, why not let apt's package manager handle those dependencies for you too.

Comment: Thanks, It's what I needed to read :D. But why the ubuntu version is so old?, it was lunched on January 2010!